# How to add the difference of two Dates to the third Date in Java?

Tags: java, date

I'm new to Java, and I did some search in google and this forum, but I'm still not sure what is a good way to do this. (Joda time is not an option to me).

```
Date d1;
Date d2;
Date d3;
float a;
```

what is a good way for me to do:

```
d3 + a - (d1 - d2);
```

Do I need to get the millisecond between d1 and d2, and then convert d3 to calendar to add the millisecond to it?

Thank you!

Edit: I should have mentioned that float a represents number of minutes, e.g. a = 35.6 minutes.

Comment: Trying to get a float and a Date together like that is almost akin to bestiality.

Comment: @paulo-ebermann a is in unit of minutes. Edited the original post. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "difference" - difference can have a direction or be absolute.

If you want to add the absolute gap, use this:

```
Date result = new Date(d3.getTime() + Math.abs(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()));
```

If you care about d2 being relative to d1 (ie if d2 is *before* d1 you actually subtract the gap), then use:

```
Date result = new Date(d3.getTime() + d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
```

**EDITED:**

In response to comments, yes: If `float a` is a number of minutes, you can further add `a * 60000` to get a new long number of milliseconds and create a new Date from that.

Comment: `a` needs to be added to the `d3.getTime() + d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()`, however float is the wrong type - dates are stored in millis and therefore cannot be a decimal

Comment: Pay attention that this may have unexpected results if daylight saving time switches are involved.

Comment: Thank you. If I want to add the float a as number of minutes, I guess it's ok for me to do Date result = new Date(d3.getTime() + a*60000 + d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()); Right?